# VB.net WindowsForm changing then [System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException]

Tags: vb.net, datatable

-I created 2 forms after I use hide() and show() to switch between form.

-In the 2nd form, I create datatable (bond to datagrid) and primary key for datatable to use find().

-After I press [BACK] button form 2nd form to 1st form (use hide() and show() function) and come back to use 2nd form application again. the runtime error show this [System.Data.Missing.PrimaryKeyException: Table doesn't have a primary key]

1st Form

```
Public Class MainMenu

    Public MainForm As MainMenu
    Public AssetCheckForm As AssetCheck

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        AssetCheckForm.Show()
        MainForm.Hide()

    End Sub

    Public Sub MainMenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MainForm = New MainMenu()
        AssetCheckForm = New AssetCheck()
    End Sub End Class
```

2nd Form

```
Dim dtAsset As New DataTable("AssetTable")

Public Sub readData()
        If readStatus = 0 Then
            Try
                Dim splits As String()
                Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(inputcsvname)
                    'read the first line for the table columns
                    splits = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
                    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(splits)
                        dtAsset.Columns.Add(splits(i))
                    Next
                    'read the rest of the lines to add rows
                    Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
                        splits = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
                        dtAsset.Rows.Add(splits)
                    Loop
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            Finally

            End Try

            dtAsset_display = dtAsset.Copy()
            totalcount.Text = getRowsCount(dtAsset_display)

            dtAsset.Columns("AsstCode").Unique = True
            dtAsset.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtAsset.Columns("AsstCode")}

            'bind display part to DataGrid
            DataGrid1.DataSource = dtAsset

Private Sub BackButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonF4.Click
    clearData()
    MainMenu.MainForm.Show()
    MainMenu.AssetCheckForm.Hide()

End Sub
```

I think I missed something about VB.net WinForm concept.
Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what your code looked like and where exactly the exception was being thrown.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I jumped in my car and went down to the shops. I bought some milk and was about to head home, but the car wouldn't start! Is there something I'm missing in the "drive my car to do shopping" concept?

Comment: To start with you should remove your exception handling. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle. Catching `Catch ex As Exception` and doing nothing is terrible.

Comment: Also, is `Option Strict On` set in your code?

Comment: The line `MainMenu.MainForm.Show()` looks dodgy. How are you creating your original `MainMenu`? Is that the one that start when the app starts?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, It is. I did'nt touch 'Option Strict'.

Comment: @Palm - Sorry, "Yes, It is. I did'nt touch 'Option Strict'." means you have it `On` or `Off`? (By default it is `Off` so you have set it?)

Comment: @Enigmativity It `Off`

Comment: @Palm - Always, 100%, make sure it is **`On`**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are calling `MainForm = New MainMenu()` in `MainForm` it means you now have **two instances** of `MainForm`.

So then when you call `MainMenu.MainForm.Show()` you are showing your new instance, not the existing one.

You need to change this around so that you store the reference to the existing `MainForm` in your `AssetCheckForm` form.

Something like this:

```
Public Class MainMenu

    Private AssetCheckForm As AssetCheckForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.AssetCheckForm = New AssetCheckForm
        Me.AssetCheckForm.MainMenu = Me
        Me.Hide()
        Me.AssetCheckForm.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class AssetCheckForm

    Friend MainMenu As MainMenu

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.MainMenu.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Af the you use `Me.AssetCheckForm = New AssetCheckForm` when I entered this form how can I refer to the variable in it. Is it `MainMenu.AssetCheckForm.(Variable)` ?

Comment: When you are in `MainMenu` it is `Me.AssetCheckForm`, but when you are in `AssetCheckForm` it is simply `Me`.

Comment: @Palm - Have you seen the special `Me` variable that refers to the current class you are in?

Comment: The problem solved. Thank you very much for your support. I tried to understand about OOP, when to use `New` and making instance.

Comment: @Palm - Never use the default instance of a form. It was a bad idea that they put that in. It just makes coding harder. I hope you have `Option Strict On` set now.